# Find all network devices on wifi lan - Found no smartphone device

Tags: cmd

I used `cmd` with `net view` in windows 8 to find all devices connected to my wifi network.

I have 2 computers and 1 smartphone connected.

Net view shows me 2 computers but does NOT show any smartphone device.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Reference [NET.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html):

> The NET Command is used to manage File Shares, Printer Shares and
>   sessions as follows:

...

> Display a **list of computers** in the current domain. NET VIEW

Your smartphone device is **not** a computer in the local domain.

**How do I find all devices connected to my wifi network?**

Try Nirsoft [Wireless Network Watcher](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html):

> Wireless Network Watcher is a small utility that scans your wireless
>   network and **displays the list of all computers and devices that are
>   currently connected to your network**.
>
> For every computer or device that is connected to your network, the
>   following information is displayed: IP address, MAC address, the
>   company that manufactured the network card, and optionally the
>   computer name.